# Identifying dynamically generated elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript

In the following code,

```
<script>
 function val()
 {
    //get alltextarea to validate
  }
$(document).ready(function() {
var html= '<form>'
html += '<textarea name="test" id="test"';
    html += '<textarea name="test1" id="test1"';
html += 'form';

$('#get_div').append();
 });

 </script>

<div id= "get_div"></div> 
<input type="button" onclick="val();"
```

The two textareas are dynamically generated.Now how to validate it in function val.When i do $('#test').val() or document.getElementbyId(test).value I could not find the values of the textareas

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

You're not generating valid HTML, there are a few problems:

- The `<textarea>` elements aren't closed.
- The `<form>` element isn't closed
- The `onclick` isn't rigged up correctly (bettter done via jQuery anyway)

Here's a corrected version with those changes that works:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var html= '<form>'
    html += '<textarea name="test" id="test"></textarea>';
    html += '<textarea name="test1" id="test1"></textarea>';
    html += '</form>';
  $('#get_div').append(html);
  $("input").click(function() {
    alert($('#test').val());        
  });
});​
```

HTML:

```
<div id= "get_div"></div> 
<input type="button" Value="TestBtn"​ />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[See a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AWT9y/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell the difference intrinsically between dynamically created elements and those from ordinary markup. What I'd suggest you do is use a marker class so:

```
$(function() {
  $("textarea").addClass("static");
  ...
});
```

Those text areas without the static class are dynamically created. This is of course a cooperative scheme as there is nothing stopping you from creating dynamic markup with the static class but, like I said, you can't do anything about that.